# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have an old database filled with info and now i want to display Category names from that DB and getting this error.

Here is my controller

```
public function forums(){

    $cats = Forum_cats::all();
    return view ('lapas.forums.index')->with('cats', $cats);
    }
}
```

here is my view

```
@if(count($cats >1))
    @foreach($cats as $cati)
        <div class = "well">
            <h3>{{$cati->description}}</hr>
        </div>
    @endforeach

@else

@endif
```

and here is screen of DB structure

http://prntscr.com/mg5nk1

Ask for more info if needed!

Comment: try replacing `@if(count($cats >1))`  with `@if($cats->count())`. Plus your `> 1` is in the wrong parentesis

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your operator is misplaced:

```
@if(count($cats) > 1)
    @foreach($cats as $cati)
        <div class = "well">
            <h3>{{$cati->description}}</hr>
        </div>
    @endforeach

@else

@endif
```

It looks like you're trying to loop through these `$cats` in a Blade template. You might also try `forelse`:

```
@forelse($cats as $cati)
  <div class = "well">
    <h3>{{$cati->description}}</hr>
  </div>
@empty
  {{-- Action if there are none --}}
@endforelse
```

Edit: Docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is wrong. Try :

```
@if($cats->count() > 1)
```